# Dynamic link based on today Date

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, custom-link

I would like to customize a button which redirects to a landing page.

If the customer clicks that link within the first 7 days after the email was sent, it goes to a landing page; if it is clicked after the first 7 days, it is redirected to another landing page.

Is it possible to do with AMPscript or in any ways in Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to do this with AMPscript as AMPscript is processed at send time in marketing cloud.

One possible workaround would be setting the link to a page on your website and this site determines to which landing page the subscriber should be redirected and does so accordingly (send date could be passed as URL-parameter and this can be done using AMPscript).